# Erro ao importar banco de dados SQL wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, mariadb

Ao tentar importar banco de dados acontece o seguinte erro:

```
Erro
Comando SQL:


CREATE TABLE `wpzm_actionscheduler_actions` (
  `action_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hook` varchar(191) COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '=utf8_general_ci' at line 3
```

Como posso resolver?

CREATE TABLE `wpzm_affiliate_wp_visits` (
`visit_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`affiliate_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`referral_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`rest_id` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`url` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`referrer` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`campaign` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`context` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`ip` tinytext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`date` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`visit_id`),
KEY `affiliate_id` (`affiliate_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Comment: Isso parece um erro de sintaxe, tenta tirar o carater ` e correr de novo.

Comment: erro Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET c' at line 5

Comment: O conteúdo do ficheiro não está completo na pergunta, crie a base de dados manualmente, e depois executa por partes (ignora as linhas do topo que começam por @@)
Basicamente precisas das tabelas, importa desde o primeiro CREATE TABLE

Answer (score -2):

Tem um erro na sua sintaxe, tente rodar essa:

CREATE TABLE wpzm_actionscheduler_actions (
action_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
hook VARCHAR(250))